# Gtk, Does deleting builder pointer deletes all the Widgets created using it

Tags: gtk

I am creating builder pointer as follows.

```
GtkBuilder *builder_ptr;
builder_ptr = gtk_builder_new();
if( ! gtk_builder_add_from_file(builder_ptr, "Test.glade", &error ) )
    printf("\n Error Builder, Exit!\n");
```

and i am deleting this builder pointer as follows:

```
g_object_unref(G_OBJECT(m_builder));
```

this builder pointer contains 2-3 GtkWindows and other widgets.
So my question is that do i need to delete all the windows in this builder manually when i delete this builder or all the windows will get destroyed when i delete builder pointer.

Thanks,
PP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The windows won't get destroyed when you delete the builder pointer.

Comment: So we need to delete all of the widgets one by one created with the glade file.

Comment: No, you just need to delete the toplevel windows.